# Laplace equation over concentric spheres

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, elliptic-pde

Is there a closed formula for the solution of Dirichlet problem ($\Delta u=0$) for annulus $r <|x| < R$, $x \in R^n$ (n>2), with two given boundary value functions, $f$ over $|x|=r$ and $g$ over $|x|=R$?

If the answer is yes, please give the formula or a reference for it.

Comment: It seems that a formula could be derived using generalized cylindrical cordinates, seperation of variables and a lot of calculation, just like in the 2D case.

Comment: It can also be established by using Fourier series.

Comment: http://www.phy.olemiss.edu/~cavaglia/courses/Phys_621/Phys_621_Schedule.html  



Comment: Of course you can.

Answer (score 2):

This is exercise 2.5 on page 29 in Gilbarg and Trudinger's book "Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order".